# PubSub model in java

Tags: java, publish-subscribe

I need to build a java application that will hit a certain api at say every 1 second which will send some data in response. The application will then push this data to multiple applications using some framework. 
I understand that this does not have to be a web app, or a web server. I am not supposed to expose an api from this server. How do I go about building this simple application?

Comment: I suggest you spend more time on design and work out specifically what you want.  It's like saying; I want a holiday which doesn't have to be to a city, how much will it cost and where should I go?

Comment: "I am not supposed to expose an api from this server." Any particular reason why you don't want to deploy your service on a web server?

Comment: You'll need a class that performs the polling, then some method of configuration for the receivers (I like to specify a Java interface for that, very useful for testing) and finally a class that performs the distributing. Logging would be useful as well, and some class doing the monitoring. Now get your ass in gear :P

Comment: Do I need to? Its because I don't find a need to. Actually what I want to make is to pull data from an api, which is not push based. And I need this data to be sent to a number of applications, so I actually want to create a layer between my applications and the website, so that my applications do not have to pull data. I will write an application to pull the data using api and make it push to wherever it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficiency would be to use multicasting UDP as means of transport: several subscribers listen to one "stream".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html as transport protocol to send 1 thing to several recipients.

To achieve that in an orchestrated way, a subscriber maybe first has to announce himself and receive a start time, and decryption token for that edition. Or in your case, to him a new start time and decryption token, to go reading are *pushed*.

For that **pushing API** I would look into the new emerging [HTML5 support](https://today.java.net/article/2010/03/31/html5-server-push-technologies-part-1) for that. As that will be mainstream. And though HTTP is not your intended protocol, it might be easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

Message.queues. Take a look at JMS Topics.
Then look at a good messaging library to make using JMS easier / cleaner, like Camel, Mule, or Spring Messaging.